# Xcode Image Asset By Device

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

My question relates to creating a custom image asset for iPad Pro. It is my understanding that the correct image from an image asset set in Xcode is picked based on the type of device in the following way:

```
iPhone:
  1x: iPhones older than iPhone 4
  2x: iPhone 4/4s, 5/5s, 6/6s
  3x: iPhone 6/6s Plus

iPad:
  1x: non-retina iPads
  2x: retina iPads (including iPad mini)
```

If this understanding is incorrect, please let me know. But if it is correct, how do I make a custom image set for iPad Pro? The images I made for the regular-size retina iPad would be too small to fit on the iPad Pro and there is no 3x option for an iPad image set.

Comment: Regular image assets are for icons and other images that appear roughly the same size regardless of device. Think of things like icons shown on tab bars and toolbars. iOS has no built in support (other than launch image asset) for images that need to fill the device's screen.

Comment: Right. But what I'm asking is if there's a way to create an image asset specifically for iPad Pro, whether or not iOS has built in support for it.

Comment: There's no way to make an image asset specific to any device. Image assets don't work like that. As I said, they are meant to be used for images that are device independent. They are only for 1x/2x/3x images that all have the same point size.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case then which image set will iPad pro load from? 2x? And if that's the case then won't all retina iPads load the same image as the one for iPad pro? Seems like a terrible waste of memory since most iPads have much smaller screens than the pro. There's really no way around this?

Comment: You can create a separate asset where you add the iPad Pro image and replace it at runtime on those devices.

Comment: I used this for iPhone 5 specific images like `my-icon@2x`, `my-icon@3x`, `my-icon~ipad` and `my-icon@2x~ipad` in a `my-icon` asset and `my-icon-iphone5@2x` in a `my-icon-iphone5` asset, and on iPhone 5 devices I use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-icon-iphone5"]`.