# Xcode Image Asset For Width-Spanning Image

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

I'm creating a universal iOS application (supports iPad and iPhone 4 and later). In this application, I have an image that spans the width of the screen on every device (and maintains a constant aspect ratio). In order to be as memory-efficient as possible, I created a version of this image for each device I support, which each version of the image sized to exactly fit on the device it's intended for.

What is the best way to store these images in my Xcode project, and load the correct image in my code?

Right now I just have 2x and 3x image assets for the image (and a 2x for iPad) and load it with the following line of code:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image"))
```

But that doesn't allow me to have a different image for, say, iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 because they both load the 2x image.

Comment: Why did you post a new question? Why not update [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167075/xcode-image-asset-by-device) to make it clear?

Comment: Because that was a completely different question?... That question was just asking if it was possible to make images specific to iPad Pro. Based on your answer to that question, I realized that I had been misusing image assets (2x and 3x images are supposed to appear at the same size on the screen) and was wondering what the correct approach was. Hence this separate question...